# Is it possible to get a row count on all of temp tables from tempdb.sys.tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to get row counts from the temp tables using code similar to below and quickly validate that the temp tables are working without typing each of them individually. I can see all of the local temp tables from the session using this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tempdb.sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#%'
```

The results I want is something like:

| name | row_count |
| --- | --- |
| #temp1 | 2000 |
| #temp2 | 0 |
| #temp3 | 0 |

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The names are not going to match exactly, but if you're using this to eyeball things, that shouldn't matter too much.

```sql
SELECT t.name, p.rows
FROM tempdb.sys.tables as t
join tempdb.sys.partitions as p
    on p.object_id = t.object_id
    and p.index_id in (0, 1)
WHERE name LIKE '#%';
```

Comment: Can you explain why you used index_id? Is it necessary?

Comment: Sure thing! I don't know anything about the temp tables in question - they may or may not have all sorts of non-clustered indexes on them. Without a predicate on index_id, row_counts for all of those indexes as well. By limiting it to index_id 0 (if the temp table is a heap) and index_id = 1 (if the temp table has a clustered index), this query will only pull back rows for the base table.